# Creating channels at the top of the file in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a channel at the top of the file.

I've tried creating the channel, but it errored with a syntax error.

```
var test make(chan string)
syntax error: unexpected ( after top level declaration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make(chan string)` is a value, NOT A TYPE.

Comment: So you're saying this isn't possible?

Comment: `var test chan string = make(chan string)`